# WSO2 DSS - odata filter did not work

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I am using wso2 v6.3.0, the odata service is working, returning all records from a table, but the `$filter=wdt_ID eq 8` did not work at all, it keeps on returning all the records! (even the `$select` did not work, it returns all the columns anyway).

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCogA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question:

After days of trials & web searches, I found my careless mistakes. I type in the addition parameters as: .....?filter=wdt_ID eq 8 , missing out the $ sign !!

So, the correct syntax should be: .....?$filter=wdt_ID eq 8 !

The odata features works as documented, excellent wso2 !